# differentiability on boundary points

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I wondered whether the following is true, or if there is some counterexample. Suppose $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Can we conclude that $f$ is differentiable in $a$ (and similarly in $b$), in other words, can we conclude that the limit
$$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$
exists(where it may be $\infty$ or $-\infty$)? From a drawing it seems 'obvious', but I know that in analysis pictures can be very misleading. I have the idea one can show convergence by using continuity in the end point and convergence of $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ when $h \to 0$ with $x$ suitably close to $a$(or $b$)... But when I try to write something down it becomes a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted, yes if $f'$ has limits at the endpoints.

No in general. For an example where the limit does not exist even in $[-\infty,\infty]$, take $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and define $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ (where of course we intend $f(0)=0$). Then $$\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\sin(1/h),$$which oscillates between $1$ and $-1$ as $h\to 0^+$.

Comment: I forgot about that beast, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer :

Let $h>0$. Applying Mean Value Theorem to $f$ on $[a,a+h]$, we obtain
$$\exists c_h\in (a,a+h), f'(c_h) = \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}.$$

Since $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0^+} c_h=a$, we have
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}  \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}= \lim_{h\to 0^+}f'(c_h) = \lim_{x\to a^+} f'(x)$$
if these limits exist...

Comment: Oops I think I can draw a counterexample, to that limit existing.  just a continuous function with 'infinite slope' on the boundary points.

Comment: In your counterexample, the limit exists but is infinite.